# How to integrate XEP-0055 in xmpp Chat app for search user in ios

Tags: ios, iphone

I am creating a XMPP chat app on iOS. I am trying to do is search user over XMPP. I checked the **opernfire** server and it has the search plugin enabled. I gone through **XEP:0055 and found the stanza.**

Answer (score 0):

See http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0055.html for reference on the format of the XML you should send and expect to receive back.

If you are trying to perform a search, here is an example for searching for a user by email address

```
    NSString *bareJID  = [self.xmppStream.myJID bare];

    NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query"];
    [query addAttributeWithName:@"xmlns" stringValue:@"jabber:iq:search"];

    NSXMLElement *email = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"email" stringValue:searchQuery];
    [query addChild:email];

    NSXMLElement *iq = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"iq"];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"set"];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"search2"];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"search.%@",self.xmppStream.myJID.domain]];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:bareJID];
    [iq addAttributeWithName:@"xml:lang" stringValue:@"en"];
    [iq addChild:query];
    [self.xmppStream sendElement:iq];
```

In your callback for xmppStream:didReceiveIQ: you will receive a response from the server, with the same id you specified above (in this case 'search2'). This will be an XML response, as indicated on the initial URL I mentioned for the XEP-0055 reference page, and you can parse it out accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can go http://blog.csdn.net/dangfm/article/details/36185879,and follow '搜索关键词' to assemble XML(iq),then _xmppStream send it(iq).